# Possible to lock a {portion} of an array in C#? or have dynamic lock array?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, dictionary, locking

I have an dynamic list of objects I am tracking, and may in the future use many threads. Can someone look at this implementation for errors?

In other words I want to track a many instances of this object:

```
object AzureBatchTrackerLock = new object();
Dictionary<string, List<TableServiceEntity>> AzureBatchTracker = new Dictionary<string, List<TableServiceEntity>>();
```

My current approach is to use `lock` with dedicated objects, and List and Dictionry to handle the dynamic arrays...

**BatchThread.cs**

```
/// This object itself contains a dictionary AND a lock.  
///  This object will ALSO be contained in a second dictionary that also has its own lock 
public class BatchThread
{ 
   // When I perform updates to AzureBatchTracker dictionary, lock the following
  internal readonly object AzureBatchTrackerLock = new object();
  internal Dictionary<string, List<TableServiceEntity>> AzureBatchTracker = new Dictionary<string, List<TableServiceEntity>>();
}
```

**BatchProcessor.cs**

```
public class BatchProcessor
{ 
 // Class-wide scope
 readonly object _BatchEntriesLock = new object();
 Dictionary<string, BatchThread> _BatchEntries = new Dictionary<string, BatchThread>();

 // The "outer loop"
 public BatchThread GetAnEntry(string ThingToProcess)
 { 
     // Prepare return variable
    BatchThread foundBatchThread = null;

    // And then I would select an object like this:
    // Notice that I'm performing what may be a concurrent entry here
    // on a non-locked object ............................
    //  Is this a bad idea?  Should I lock?  Does it matter?
    //  If I must lock, want to exit as quickly as possible. Must not be later than the next lock() command
    var activeRow = _BatchEntries[ThingToProcess];


    // Since I have the object I care about, I'll work with the "secondary" lock object 
    // It works in practice, but I don't know what kind concurrency issues I'll run into.
    lock (activeRow.Value.AzureBatchTrackerLock)
    {
       // Add and remove from the collection 
       ActiveRow.Value.AzureBatchTracker.Add(new exampleEntry); 

       // Do Stuff

       ActiveRow.Value.AzureBatchTracker.Remove(something);

         foundBatchThread =  activeRow.Value.AzureBatchTracker[ThingToProcess];
     }

     return foundBatchThread;
   }

   // The inner loop
   // Called whenever the "Outer" array needs to be expanded
   public void AddNewBatchEntry(string newEntryName)
   {  
     lock (_BatchEntriesLock)
      {
         // Add placeholder to the collection
         _BatchEntries.Add( newEntryName, new BatchThread() ); 

          // Do Stuff

       }
   }
  }
```

Do you see any flaws in this implementation?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to lock on
`var ActiveRow = BatchEntries[ThingToProcess];`, because you're also adding to the dictionary (unless you're sure they happen at seperate times). If you can gaurantee you won't be adding while the 'outer loop' is executing, then no, you don't need to lock - you can have concurrent reads.

If the add method happens rarely, with lots of reads, you should look into [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx)

Comment: I'll be reading up on that class shortly.  I suppose MSDN will tell me why it's preferred over `Lock`

Answer (score 4):

If you're on .NET 4.0, you can use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).

Comment: Agreed, no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware the new class existed!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know whether your locks are at the right level without knowing how this code will be used, but if your outer loop is executed in a single thread, it looks ok (besides being hard to read because your use of uppercase local variable names, which makes everything look `public`). Optimization-wise, you should avoid the use of `lock` and implement [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) instead.

Comment: Just cleaned up the variables.  Thanks for reviewing/bringing it to my attention. I'll have to investigate that ReaderWriterLockSlim